# Different Volumes for Headphone and internal speakers

Tags: windows, laptop, audio, drivers

I have hp envy laptop with beats audio. It has got 4 speakers, 2 on the front and 2 on the button of the laptop.

Without IDT audio driver, front speaks don't work. But with IDT audio driver windows does not switch volumes between internal speakers and headphone when headphone are plugged/un-plugged. This causes unbearably loud volumes with headphone when headphones are plugged in and almost no sound though internal speakers when headphones are unplugged. I have to constantly re-adjust the volume.

On my older laptops I fixed this issue by replacing hp's audio drivers with microsoft ones. But this solution is not feasible given that two main speaks don't work without hp's drivers.

This should be major issue for all laptop users, but I haven't found any solution for this problem on online forums.

Laptop Model: [HP ENVY TouchSmart 15-j137tx](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-15-j100-Notebook-PC-series/5401191/model/6754027)

OS: Windows 10.

Edit: On Ubuntu I use hda-jack-retask to get all the speakers to work.

Comment: Do you see "Speakers" AND "Headphones" in Control Panel -> Sound (-> Playback) with disabled and disconnected devices showing (right click and check them)? Coz if the driver does not split the ports into two devices, Windows will not be able to store different volume for them. So I think the only way is probably requesting the vendor to fix the driver in that case. https://ptpb.pw/ESX0.PNG

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is Driver independent if they include this feature or not. All my past laptops have not included this feature in Windows. But Ubuntu has it included in their default drivers. So if you REALLY want it you could switch OS.

Another "easyer" fix is to have a small USB soundcard. Plug your headphones into that and set the new USB soundcard as the default sound-card. Windows saves the different sound levels and automaticly switches between them when you plug/unplug the soundcard.

EDIT: Othervise I would recommend just sending an email to the Driver manufacturer and ask them if its a hidden feature or if they could implement it in the next driver update.